# Web API & Email configuration in Simple Email Service

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api

We have a Web API (ASP.NET) hosted in a Windows instance of AWS. We have configured the SMTP settings in the web.config file like below:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="someemail@gmail.com" port="587" 
                     password="123456" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Web API sends a confirmation email a user registers a new account in the system. When we test it locally everything works fine. However, when we deploy it to Windows Server instance on AWS, it doesn't work straight away.

To make it work we have to configure the email address (i.e.`someemail@gmail.com` in this case) in the Simple Email Service. Which is OK but every time when this email changes, we have to make a similar change in the Simple Email Service.

Is there some way to bypass this configuration in AWS. By the way, we also have a Java API running on a Linux instance of AWS and there we don't have to do this type of configuration. Java API successfully sends the email.

Comment: aws throttle smtp ports on ec2 try to find limits by raising a support ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the AWS SES Account is placed in the Amazon SES sandbox.

You can tell if your account is still in the sandbox in the AWS Region that you selected, you see a blue banner at the top of the sending statistics page that says "Your Amazon SES account has "sandbox" access in region"

Click on the "Request a Sending Limit Increase" link
The full instructions can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console)..

Answer (score 0):

aws having SES email sending limit. you can contact support centre for information and tell them to increase the limit to send emails more.

Comment: I don't have any issue with the limit on the number of emails sent. The issue is that I have to verify my "FROM" email with Amazon SES then it allows me to send email using ASP.NET. I want to know if there is a way to bypass this as the customer wants to change the address whenever they want without any configuration changes in AWS.

Comment: yes you can change the config whenever you want in aws.you can go to ses and change email you have verified .